# Laravel testing input file array

Tags: arrays, forms, file, laravel, testing

How I fill a form like this using Laravel's `attach()` method when writing my tests?

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
```

Obviously this won't work:

```
$this->attach('photo1.jpg', 'photo[]');
$this->attach('photo2.jpg', 'photo[]');
$this->attach('photo3.jpg', 'photo[]');
```

I did try using `fillForm()` and `submitForm()` with no luck.

I've been searching how to solve this, but I can't figure it out.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have three inputs with the same name?

Comment: Some more info here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-do-i-test-a-multiple-file-upload-field-in-laravelphpunit and here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12620 - hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, is an input file array.

Comment: Hi @JoelHinz I already read these articles, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you having trouble filling the form or submitting the form? Can you submit the form without attaching anything?

Comment: No problem without attaching anything. Only when I call `attach('photo.jpg', 'photo[]')` test fail with message `InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field ""`